# How do I modify the body of a function in an eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I've managed to create a popup menu and get a `IMethod`, but I don't know how to modify the method.  For this example, assume that I want to add the text `system.out.println("Hello, world!");` to the bottom of the existing method when the button is clicked.

What I currently have is below:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.IObjectActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod;

public class HelloWorldAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {

    private Shell shell;

    private IMethod currentMethod;

    /**
     * Constructor for Action1.
     */
    public HelloWorldAction() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see IObjectActionDelegate#setActivePart(IAction, IWorkbenchPart)
     */
    public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
        shell = targetPart.getSite().getShell();
    }

    /**
     * @see IActionDelegate#run(IAction)
     */
    public void run(IAction action) {
        //TODO: preform the actions.
    }

    /**
     * @see IActionDelegate#selectionChanged(IAction, ISelection)
     */
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
        if (!(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)) {
            action.setEnabled(false);
            return;
        }
        IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;

        if (!(sel.getFirstElement() instanceof IMethod)) {
            //Only handles IMethods.
            action.setEnabled(false);
            return;
        }

        action.setEnabled(true);
        this.currentMethod = (IMethod) sel.getFirstElement();
    }
}
```

I'm stuck on modifying the `currentMethod`.  I've seen [this help page on modifying code](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_manip.htm), but I don't know how to get a `Document`, `AST`, or really any of the things needed from an `IMethod`.  What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

As per [Eclipse API](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_manip.htm):

> Modifying a compilation unit Most simple modifications of Java source
>   can be done using the Java element API.
>
> For example, you can query a type from a compilation unit. Once you
>   have the IType, you can use protocols such as createField,
>   createInitializer, createMethod, or createType to add source code
>   members to the type. The source code and information about the
>   location of the member is supplied in these methods.

I would try using:

```
currentMethod.getCompilationUnit().getTypes()[0].createMethod(" hello world code goes here ",null,true,null); 
//not sure if progress monitor can be null, please check
```

As per [Eclipse API](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2FIType.html):

> IMethod createMethod(String contents,
>                        IJavaElement sibling,
>                        boolean force,
>                        IProgressMonitor monitor)
>                        throws JavaModelException
>
> Creates and returns a method or constructor in this type with the given contents.
>   Optionally, the new element can be positioned before the specified
>   sibling. If no sibling is specified, the element will be appended to
>   this type.
>
> It is possible that a method with the same signature already exists in
>   this type. The value of the force parameter affects the resolution of
>   such a conflict:
>
> **true** - in this case the method is created with the new contents
>
> **false** - in this case a JavaModelException is thrown

Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: This is useful (though I solved it a different way), but it doesn't append text to the existing method.  But it helps.  I'll post an answer with the solution I used.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this figured out.

The following is based off of [the example of using AST from the documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_manip.htm) and **appends** the text `System.out.println("Hello" + " world");` to the end of the existing function.

```
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.text.Document;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.text.edits.TextEdit;
import org.eclipse.ui.IObjectActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.ICompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.IMethod;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.*;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite;

public class HelloWorldAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {

    private Shell shell;

    private IMethod currentMethod;

    /**
     * Constructor for Action1.
     */
    public AddFace2() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see IObjectActionDelegate#setActivePart(IAction, IWorkbenchPart)
     */
    public void setActivePart(IAction action, IWorkbenchPart targetPart) {
        shell = targetPart.getSite().getShell();
    }

    /**
     * @see IActionDelegate#run(IAction)
     */
    public void run(IAction action) {
        //Following is based off of the sample at http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fjdt_api_manip.htm

        try {
            ICompilationUnit cu = currentMethod.getCompilationUnit(); 
            String source = cu.getSource();
            Document document= new Document(source);


            //Get the compilation unit for traversing AST
            final ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
            parser.setSource(currentMethod.getCompilationUnit());
            parser.setResolveBindings(true);

            final CompilationUnit compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

            // record modification - to be later written with ASTRewrite
            compilationUnit.recordModifications();

            // Get AST node for IMethod
            int methodIndex = currentMethod.getCompilationUnit().getSource().indexOf(currentMethod.getSource());

            //Convert to a MethodDeclaration.
            MethodDeclaration methodASTNode = (MethodDeclaration)NodeFinder.perform(compilationUnit.getRoot(), methodIndex, currentMethod.getSource().length());

            ASTRewrite rewrite = ASTRewrite.create(compilationUnit.getAST());

            Block blockOld = methodASTNode.getBody();

            //Create a copy of the old block.
            AST blockAST = AST.newAST(AST.JLS8);
            Block block = (Block) Block.copySubtree(blockAST, blockOld);

            //Add "System.out.println("hello" + " world");".
            MethodInvocation methodInvocation = blockAST.newMethodInvocation();

            QualifiedName name =  blockAST.newQualifiedName(
                    blockAST.newSimpleName("System"),
                    blockAST.newSimpleName("out"));

            methodInvocation.setExpression(name);
            methodInvocation.setName(blockAST.newSimpleName("println")); 
            InfixExpression infixExpression = blockAST.newInfixExpression();
            infixExpression.setOperator(InfixExpression.Operator.PLUS);
            StringLiteral literal = blockAST.newStringLiteral();
            literal.setLiteralValue("Hello");
            infixExpression.setLeftOperand(literal);
            literal = blockAST.newStringLiteral();
            literal.setLiteralValue(" world");
            infixExpression.setRightOperand(literal);
            methodInvocation.arguments().add(infixExpression);
            ExpressionStatement expressionStatement = blockAST.newExpressionStatement(methodInvocation);
            block.statements().add(expressionStatement);

            rewrite.replace(blockOld, block, null);


            // computation of the text edits
            TextEdit edits = rewrite.rewriteAST(document, cu.getJavaProject().getOptions(true));

            // computation of the new source code
            edits.apply(document);
            String newSource = document.get();

            // update of the compilation unit
            cu.getBuffer().setContents(newSource);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }

    /**
     * @see IActionDelegate#selectionChanged(IAction, ISelection)
     */
    public void selectionChanged(IAction action, ISelection selection) {
        if (!(selection instanceof IStructuredSelection)) {
            action.setEnabled(false);
            return;
        }
        IStructuredSelection sel = (IStructuredSelection) selection;

        if (!(sel.getFirstElement() instanceof IMethod)) {
            //Only handles IMethods.
            action.setEnabled(false);
            return;
        }

        action.setEnabled(true);
        this.currentMethod = (IMethod) sel.getFirstElement();
    }

}
```